# xargs doesn't work on Mac when given output from 'git branch'

Tags: macos, git, xargs

I want to remove the matching branch.

```
$ 
demon@bogon solo$ git branch |grep bug_
  bug_1255
  bug_1279
  bug_1280
  bug_1286
  bug_1311
  bug_1315
  bug_1317
  bug_1329
  bug_1335
  bug_1356
  bug_1361
  bug_1372
  bug_1375
  bug_1402
  bug_1406
demon@bogon solo$ git branch |grep bug_ | xargs git branch -D
error: branch 'bug_1255' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1279' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1280' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1286' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1311' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1315' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1317' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1329' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1335' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1356' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1361' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1372' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1375' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1402' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1406' not found.
demon@bogon solo$ git branch -D bug_1406
Deleted branch bug_1406 (was 509e606).
```

```
demon@bogon solo$ git branch | grep bug_ | od -c
0000000          033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g
0000020    _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1   2   5   5  \n         033   [
0000040    0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m
0000060  033   [   K   1   2   7   9  \n         033   [   0   1   ;   3
0000100    1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1
0000120    2   8   0  \n         033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [
0000140    K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1   2   8   6  \n
0000160          033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g
0000200    _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1   3   1   1  \n         033   [
0000220    0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m
0000240  033   [   K   1   3   1   5  \n         033   [   0   1   ;   3
0000260    1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1
0000300    3   1   7  \n         033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [
0000320    K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1   3   2   9  \n
0000340          033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g
0000360    _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1   3   3   5  \n         033   [
0000400    0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m
0000420  033   [   K   1   3   5   6  \n         033   [   0   1   ;   3
0000440    1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1
0000460    3   6   1  \n         033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [
0000500    K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1   3   7   2  \n
0000520          033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g
0000540    _ 033   [   m 033   [   K   1   3   7   5  \n         033   [
0000560    0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   b   u   g   _ 033   [   m
0000600  033   [   K   1   4   0   2  \n                                
0000610

demon@bogon solo$ git branch |grep bug_ | xargs echo git branch -D
git branch -D bug_1255 bug_1279 bug_1280 bug_1286 bug_1311 bug_1315 bug_1317 bug_1329 bug_1335 bug_1356 bug_1361 bug_1372 bug_1375 bug_1402
demon@bogon solo$ git branch |grep bug_ | xargs -n 1 git branch -D
error: branch 'bug_1255' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1279' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1280' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1286' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1311' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1315' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1317' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1329' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1335' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1356' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1361' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1372' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1375' not found.
error: branch 'bug_1402' not found.
```

Comment: that error is coming from `git` not `xargs`, is there some environment variable git needs that is not exported?

Comment: @Joe, But these branches already exist, I can delete by git branch -D branch

Comment: What's with the `:(` and `:)` in the commands — or is it in the prompts?  Does it indicate failure/success (`:(` / `:)`) or the previous command?  If so, then I suggest it is cute but inappropriate on SO.  Use a plain `$ ` as a prompt for regular users, and `# ` as a prompt for root users if absolutely necessary (though most appropriate questions on SO won't need root privilege).

Comment: Have you got colourization (or however it is spelled) on forcibly?  If so, the trouble is that the branch names are not plain text but have escape characters and all sorts in the names, which is why they aren't found.  You could try `git branch | grep bug_ | od -c` (or use your preferred character dump program).

Comment: try `git branch |grep bug_ | xargs echo git branch -D` to make sure the command is doing what you think, you may need to do 1 at a time with `git branch |grep bug_ | xargs -n 1 git branch -D`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Yes, You are right. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked if you have colourization turned on forcibly, and the answer appears to be yes.

To fix, find your `~/.gitconfig` and change the colour stanza to more like:

```
[color]
        ui = auto
```

That does not force coloured output; if the output goes to a pipe, the colouring is dropped.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because I set too alias grep='grep --color=always' cause it?

Comment: Ah, yes; that (an alias for `grep` that colourizes the selected output always) would explain it better, in fact!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't with OSX or xargs

```
mycroft:msg sja$ git branch bug
mycroft:msg sja$ git branch
  bug
* master
mycroft:msg sja$ git branch | grep bug | xargs git branch -D
Deleted branch bug (was 32c55a4).
mycroft:msg sja$ git branch
* master
mycroft:msg sja

mycroft:msg sja$ git branch bug_xxx
mycroft:msg sja$ git branch | grep bug_xxx | xargs git branch -D
Deleted branch bug_xxx (was 32c55a4).
mycroft:msg sja$ git branch
* master
mycroft:msg sja$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print only the matching part of the lines using `-o` option of `grep`.

```
$ git branch | grep -Eo "bug_[0-9]+" | xargs git branch -D
```

`grep -Eo "bug_[0-9]+"` prints branch names without colourization characters.

---

I found easier solution. Try `--no-color` option.

`$ git branch --no-color | grep _bug | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: Have you tried adding "alias grep = 'grep --color=always'" and then try it?